# Parse Local Datastore: Unpin objects seems broken in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, local-datastore

I want to unpin a list of objects, which I had successfully locally stored earlier, and replace it with a new one.  The code below should do that trick, but the locally pinned objects simply don't get updated.  I tried everything including PFObject.unpin, nothing removes the old pinned objects except a complete reset of the simulator

```
func updateCountryList(server:Int, local:Int) {
    let query = VEPCountry.queryAll()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            // throw error
        } else {
            if local != 0 {
                VEPState.unpinAllObjectsWithName(String("countryListVersion\(local)"))
            }
            VEPState.pinAll(objects, withName: String("countryListVersion\(server)"))
            defaults.setObject(server, forKey: "localCountryListVersion")
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate help or pointer to known issues around unpinning in Swift

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Parse iOS SDK 1.6.2  -> the latest, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Why are the pin names different for the unpin and pin methods?

Comment: I use a new pin name for the next set, so next time round the new pin is the old pin for unpinning. Shouldn't make a difference.  I also tried with the same name, and the problem didn't go away

Comment: same problem as you. Unpin is not working. I tried with instance method and static one. It change nothing. My object is still present when I query the local storage... any solution ?

Comment: no, not yet.  I'm still praying for a solution falling from the sky :) Have been working days on it...  I also uninstalled and reinstalled the app, but the local datastore seems to be kept...

Comment: Still no solution? same problem here

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your unpin has't really finished, it's going off to the database after all.

Can you try:

```
query
  .findObjectsInBackground()
  .continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    // ...
    return VEPState.unpinAllObjectsWithNameInBackground("name"))
  })
  .continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    // ...
    return VEPState.pinAllInBackground(objects, withName: "name"))
  })
```

I may have the syntax a little off and the background method names not quite right. Also I'm using promises/tasks which is not a bad habit to get into.